# lua: Reset data weekly on specific day

Tags: lua

Having some issues with the code below.
It's supposed to reset once a week on the day the user sets, but it wont reset

There is a function that calls SC.WeekStart whenever the user reloads or opens the app.

The two values:

```
["options"]["dateweek"] = SC.WeekStart(); --returns Mon Aug from wday

["options"].weekstart = 1  --is set by user
```

Function that checks the value:

```
function SC.WeekStart()
   oneday = 86400;
   ct = time();
   dt = date("*t",ct);
   thisDay = dt["wday"];

while thisDay ~= ["options"].weekstart do
    ct = ct - oneday;
    dt = date("*t",ct);
    thisDay = dt["wday"];
  end
   cdate = date(nil,ct);
   return string.sub(cdate,0,8);`
end
```

Check if it's a new week and reset

```
if ["options"]["dateweek"] ~= SC.WeekStart() then
    DEBUG_CHAT_FRAME:AddMessage("DEBUG: New week found!");
    for mode,value in next,SC.data do
        SC.data[mode]["Week"] = {In = 0, Out = 0};
    end
 end
```

Any ideas what the problem could be and if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: `while thisDay ~= ["options"].weekstart do`, why not `if`

Comment: also should not `time` be `os.time` and `os.date`

Answer (score 1):

There’s a sense that you are doing much more than you need to. Here’s a simple check on the current weekday (Sunday is 1 in the Lua `os` library):

```
local userResetDay = 1
if os.date("*t").wday == userResetDay then
    print("reset!")
else
    print("No reset! Enjoy your day!")
end
```

Adapt to your needs.